# Factory initialization with additonal property injection

Tags: swift, typhoon

In my demo project I replaced the manual creation of a view controller with the factory-based creation within an assembly like so (as Jasper Blues demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24227246/397898)

```
// ApplicationAssembly

dynamic func mainStoryboard() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TyphoonStoryboard.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith("Main")
            initializer.injectParameterWith(self)
            initializer.injectParameterWith(NSBundle.mainBundle())
        }

        definition.scope = TyphoonScope.Singleton
    }
}

// PersonListAssembly

dynamic func personListViewController() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withFactory(self.applicationAssembly.mainStoryboard(), selector: "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:", parameters: {
            (factoryMethod) in

            factoryMethod.injectParameterWith("PersonListViewController")
        })
    }
```

But the view controller still needs some other dependencies. How can I inject the propery when doing this?

And actually I have two questions: All IBOutlets are nil, when I try to use the view controller like this. Am I missing something?

**Correct answer based on Jasper's response**

```
dynamic func personListViewController() -> AnyObject {

    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(PersonListViewController.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.factory = self.applicationAssembly.mainStoryboard()
        definition.useInitializer("instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:", parameters: { (factoryMethod) in

            factoryMethod.injectParameterWith("PersonListViewController")
        })

        definition.injectProperty("presenter", with: self.personListPresenter())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the shortcut way of declaring a component that is emitted from another Typhoon component does not support this (yet). We'll [open an issue](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/271). Meanwhile you can fall back to Typhoon 1.0 style API:

```
- (id)currentTheme
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[PFTheme class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
    {
        definition.factory = [self themeFactory];
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(sequentialTheme)];
    }];
}
```

. . when you use this approach:

- An initializer (with or without args) is actually an instance method on the object that will produce the component.
- Additional properties, scope, etc can be set.

We created the short way as its a little confusing to refer to an 'initializer' that is in fact an instance method on the class creating the component. It looks like there was an oversight in adding a configuration block.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll update my question text to provide the correct code I use now.