# Typhoon - Auto-Injection of protocol defined via factory definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

Depending on whether the app runs on an iPhone or iPad, I'd like to inject a different UIViewController, both of which implement a certain protocol. I use multiple storyboards, so I have created this factory definition for Typhoon:

```
- (id <DrawerProtocol>)drawerProtocol {
  return [TyphoonDefinition
    withFactory:self.storyboardAssembly.mainStoryboard
    selector:@selector(instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:)
    parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *factoryMethod) {
      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [factoryMethod injectParameterWith:StoryboardIdentifierDrawerIPhone];
      }
      else {
        [factoryMethod injectParameterWith:StoryboardIdentifierDrawerIPad];
      }
    }
    configuration:^(TyphoonFactoryDefinition *definition) {
      definition.classOrProtocolForAutoInjection = object_getClass(@protocol(DrawerProtocol));
      // Also tried:
      // definition.classOrProtocolForAutoInjection = @protocol(DrawerProtocol);
    }];
}
```

StoryboardAssembly provides references to all of my storyboards like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24227246/5375652).

When using auto-injection for UIViewControllers, I found that I have to set `definition.classOrProtocolForAutoInjection` in order for Typhoon to find the correct factory. However, I cannot figure out how to set this variable when injecting a protocol.

Assigning `object_getClass(@protocol(DrawerProtocol))` produces the following exception: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No components defined which satisify type: 'id<DrawerProtocol>''`.
When assigning `@protocol(DrawerProtocol)`, this happens: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Protocol isSubclassOfClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

How can I auto-inject a protocol instantiated using a factory?